# Usage of [0] with visual effects in jquery

Tags: jquery

Why selecting via [0] in jquery does not work with visual effects??

```
$("p")[0].slideUp(); /* it does not work*/
$("p").eq(0).slideUp(); /* it works */
```

As mentioned, I know there are some other ways to select the first p, but I am eager to know why the above mentioned code is not working...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.slideUp()` is a jQuery method and will work on a jQuery object.

`$("p").eq(0)` produces a jQuery object which has a `.slideUp()` method (so it works).

`$("p")[0]` produces a DOM object that does NOT have a .`slideUp()` method (so it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

`$("p")[0]` converts the jQuery object to a raw Node element and then you cannot call jQuery methods like `slideUp()` on it. but `eq(0)` is a jQuery method, selects the first `p` element and returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

`[0]` and `eq(0)` are NOT equivalent. `[0]` grabs the original DOM element, and `eq(0)` reduces the collection to the first match.

Answer (score 0):

`$("p")[0].slideUp();`  gives you the element not *jQuery object* and so jQuery methods doesn't worked here.

But,

`$("p").eq(0).slideUp();` here, `eq(0)` return the first `p` as *jQuery object* on which jQuery methods works.

`slideUp()` is a *jQuery method* which works only on *jQuery object* not in raw node element.